# does not contain definition for 'Test.dll' Properties.Resources.testdll

Tags: c#, dll

hi im trying to load a dll from resources into a process and i use this

```
pszLibFileRemote = Application.StartupPath + (loginloader.Properties.Resources.TestDLL);
```

and this is not working, i have the dll called test.dll in resources folder.
also it is possible to build the program and have the dll inside it so it can't get leaked?

here is the screenshot of the rest of the code
[image: code]

Comment: That variable is undefined so what were you expecting.

Comment: im still new to coding so could you explain me how i can define it?